# The googleapis file upload code works when running on the node console, but not when imported as a function in the project

Tags: node.js, google-api, electron, google-drive-api, filesystems

I am creating an application with electron and I am trying to upload images to googledirve with googleapis, however I have been trying for several days to make my code work since running the function creates the folder and creates the file but with size 0 bites, thought that er problem of fs.createReadStream however I run the same function by node console and this load the file correctly, the code is

```
const fs = require('fs')
const { google } = require('googleapis')

const GOOGLE_API_FOLDER_ID = '1WONK0L9hDlNTfWKEYV1eyZXiXIw-yXAE'

const keyFile = 'D:\\AppEscritorio\\salud\\config.json'
const scopes = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
const auth = new google.auth.GoogleAuth({
    keyFile,
    scopes
})

const driveService = google.drive({
    version: 'v3',
    auth
})

async function subirImagen() {

try {
    const fileMetadatafolder = {
        name: 'nuevo folder',
        parents: [GOOGLE_API_FOLDER_ID],
        mimeType: 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder',
    }
    const file = await driveService.files.create({
        resource: fileMetadatafolder,
        fields: 'id'
    })
    console.log(file.data.id)

    const fileMetaDataImg = {
        'name': 'snowplace.png',
        'parents': [file.data.id]
    }

    console.log(fd)
    const media = {
        mimeType: 'image/pmg',
        body:fs.createReadStream('D:\\Users\\RJHR\\OneDrive\\Imágenes\\5x7.PNG')
    }

   const response = await driveService.files.create({
        resource: fileMetaDataImg,
        media: media,
        field: 'id'
    })
    //return 
    console.log(response.data.id)

} catch (err) {
    console.log('Upload file error', err)
}
}

subirImagen()


module.exports = { subirImagen }
```

when importing the function upload Imagen and run it from another achivo creates everything but the file with size 0 bit

[as in the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uJXKj.png) 
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uJXKj.png]

displays the id of the folder and the created file
[id folder and file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RjTyl.png)
when running it on console con node google.js  it raise it correctly
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RjTyl.png]

[execute and print id](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hlWXG.png)
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hlWXG.png]

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0vkBe.png)
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0vkBe.png]

someone could explain this behavior, I clarify that it is the same code for both cases

this is the repositorye of de code https://github.com/Rafahur03/electron-salud.git

Comment: My guess is that you cannot access your local file when you run this with Electron. Can you check whether that's the case? Since this works when you call it via Node console, I don't think there's any problem with how your code is calling Drive API.

Comment: At first I thought that was it, surely I was not accessing the file but when I sent fs.create readStream to the console, we got our message that perfectly loaded the file in both cases, I was even able to print the buffer

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by `when I sent fs.create readStream to the console`, could you clarify that?

Comment: I print the buffer and the data returned by fs.create readstream, it throws out exactly the same data in both cases the only difference is that running it from the project where the file descritor property fails is returned with a numericoy value not as null, the project where this value works well is returned as null

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand `the project where the file descritor property fails is returned with a numericoy value not as null, the project where this value works well is returned as null`.

Comment: yes, the project where this value works well returns it as null, however I do not think that is the cause of why not load the image well in google diver

Comment: My guess is that, when calling `fs.createReadStream('D:\\Users\\RJHR\\OneDrive\\Imágenes\\5x7.PNG')` from the console you can grab the image, but not when you run this on Electron. Beyond this, I don't understand your explanations. I don't know what `file descritor property` means, and what `numericoy value` means. Consider providing a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to test this.

Comment: I’m sorry, I’ll try to be clearer, we’ve moved away from the problem in essence let’s forget about fs.createReadStream. I have a js file called google.js where I have a function that loads an image to google driver using the googleapis with npm, the problem is that if this function I run it in the node console with the command node google.js my code runs well and loads the image correctly, however when exporting this function and requiring it in another js file of my project the function runs but the image that is created in drive has a size of 0 bite,

Comment: and this happens regardless of the location of the image or the google.js file where it is my function of loading a driver. As it is possible this being the same code in both cases, in this repository is the code https://github.com/Rafahur03/electron-salud.git and this link is of a disucion on the subject in github https:/github.com/googleapis-apinod-ejs-client/issues/2660#issuecomment1283609373 however for my little experience, part of the code is not etendible to me. I really appreciate your patience and help